# Prometheus + Python How to collect several metrics from different Docker containers?

Tags: python, docker, prometheus, fastapi, metrics

For example, I have a FastAPI app with launched `prometheus_fastapi_instrumentator`, which collects metrics of the FastAPI app & my custom metrics. But I want have my custom metrics from jobs (which are without FastAPI), but I don't need system metrics and so on.

How can I add metrics from another Docker container? Or how to add a second target from jobs, without system metrics, and without `prometheus_fastapi_instrumentator`?